# Handle errors of external programs

Tags: windows, powershell, error-handling

I'm writing a PowerShell scripts that executes external programs and other scripts.

I'm calling the .exe and .ps1 script in the main script as below :

```
& ./directory/file.exe

or

& ./directory/script.ps1
```

How can I catch errors ?

Is it like unix, I can use `$?` and do something like that:

```
if($? -ne 0) then exit 1 ...
```

Is this the best way ?
Can we use **EXIT** with PowerShell?

By the way, is using "&" the best way to call .exe file ? .ps1 ?

Answer (score 0):

`$?` in powershell is boolean, and only reflects the execution status of the previous *powershell statement*.

For external programs, inspect `$LASTEXITCODE`:

```
& .\directory\file.exe 
if($LASTEXITCODE){
    return 
}
```

In the example above I use `return` - `exit` would work as well, but I generally avoid using `exit` since it'll instructs the host application to quit immediately, which may or may not be desirable if you want to call your script from another script as part of a larger operation in the future.

The invokcation operator `&` will work perfectly fine with both executables and powershell script file paths.

Comment: `exit` inside the script will exit only that script not entire host.

Comment: It looks like it does not work well with $LastExitCode.
I failed mail.exe on purpose. 

when using below, the return code is 0 even if the email.exe failed.
The value of $LastExitCode is 0.

& mail.exe email -el $eml -smt $smtp_server
if($LastExitCode > 0) 
{
write-host "Error sending email"
exit 5
}

write-host "Email success"

when using below, it works.

& mail.exe email -el $eml -smt $smtp_server
if(! $?) 
{
write-host "Error sending email"
exit 5
}

write-host "Email success"

I don't understand why

Comment: @Linus Change `$LastExitCode > 0` to `$LastExitCode -gt 0` - `>` is a stream redirection operator

Comment: It does not work even with the -gt 0. I will go with the $?, it's the only way I can catch an error